# How to Object pool for event Listeners in Java or JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, garbage-collection, object-pooling

I been reading articles about how object pooling reduces the garbage collection for games, especially for event listeners where the key event is constantly being created and destroyed. They mention how object pooling would decrease the memory problem but nowhere in code does it say how to actually do it.

How do you object pool for events in JavaScript or Java?

Comment: For the most part, object pooling is not recommended, except for objects that for some reason are very expensive to construct.   See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/115163/is-object-pooling-a-deprecated-technique.

Comment: But what about for game development where the key and mouse events are just constantly created. Wouldn't a object pool reduce the GC in java and javascript especially for devices like a android phone

Comment: Can't say much about javascript, but for Java the JVM in most cases will do a more efficient job managing the lifecycle of your objects than a custom-written pool will.

Comment: Thanks but I still mostly want to know about JavaScript since its really slower than Java

Comment: The tricky thing about trying to pool AWT/Swing events is that you don't actually have control over the code which creates them. Event dispatch is normally handled by java.awt.Component which will use some OS specific code somewhere in com.sun.* hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For object pooling in general you basically need to maintain your own list of available objects. It works nicely if all the objects are the same type. If say you have a class Thing you might have a ThingPool

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;

public class ThingPool {

    public static class Thing {

    }
    // start with a big stack of objects
    Deque<Thing> stack = new ArrayDeque<Thing>(1000);
    /**
     * Gets a new instance. If one exists in the stack use that,
     * otherwise create a new one.
     * @return
     */
    public Thing getThing() {
        if(stack.isEmpty())
            return new Thing();
        return stack.pop();
    }
    /**
     * Does not actually delete it, just stores it for later use
     * @param thing
     */
    public void deleteThing(Thing thing) {
        stack.push(thing);
    }
    /**
     * You may need to clear your pool at some point
     * if you have a great many objects in it 
     */
    public void clear() {
        stack.clear();
    }
}
```

I used this technique in C when I was doing some heavy work with many matrices of a few different know sizes and was suffering from heap fragmentation problems.

I've not used it in Java which has much better memory management than C.

Comment: Thanks! but how would i be able to store a object like for say keyevent from a listener

Comment: You might be able to do it by writing your own version of java.awt.Toolkit. This will be hard work and full of problems. 

Most likely a case of Premature Optimisation. If you think about it the fastest you might expect events to be created is 10 a second. This is very slow in computer terms, you'll redraw the screen much faster than you will need to create and process events.

Comment: I know but i was wondering since i know that the best way to make a game faster would be changing the rendering like javascript canvas to webgl and android java canvas to opengl es but i dont know that so i wanted to use smaller ones in the meantimes to make game faster